# AzurePolicy for activating DiagnosticSetting on Azure Postgesql flexible server

Tags: azure-policy, azure-postgresql

I'm writing an Azure policy for activating logs and diagnostic setting for postgresql Flexible server. However it doesn't get applied and I see this message:

```
Reason for non-compliance
No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code: Not Found)
Existence condition
Type
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings
Name
setByPolicy
```

Here is my policy-definition:

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      },
      "logAnalytics": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Log Analytics workspace",
          "description": "Select Log Analytics workspace from dropdown list.",
          "strongType": "omsWorkspace"
        }
      },
      "logsEnabled": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Enable logs",
          "description": "Whether to enable logs stream to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      },
      "metricsEnabled": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Enable metrics",
          "description": "Whether to enable metrics stream to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      },
      "profileName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Profile name",
          "description": "The diagnostic settings profile name"
        },
        "defaultValue": "setbypolicy"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "equals": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers",
        "field": "type"
      },
      "then": {
        "details": {
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "parameters": {
                "location": {
                  "value": "[field('location')]"
                },
                "logAnalytics": {
                  "value": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                },
                "logsEnabled": {
                  "value": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                },
                "metricsEnabled": {
                  "value": "[parameters('metricsEnabled')]"
                },
                "profileName": {
                  "value": "[parameters('profileName')]"
                },
                "resourceName": {
                  "value": "[field('name')]"
                }
              },
              "template": {
                "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "outputs": {},
                "parameters": {
                  "location": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "logAnalytics": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "logsEnabled": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "metricsEnabled": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "profileName": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "resourceName": {
                    "type": "String"
                  }
                },
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/', 'Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                    "properties": {
                      "logs": [
                        {
                          "category": "PostgreSQLLogs",
                          "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                        }
                      ],
                      "metrics": [
                        {
                          "category": "AllMetrics",
                          "enabled": "[parameters('metricsEnabled')]",
                          "retentionPolicy": {
                            "days": 0,
                            "enabled": false
                          },
                          "timeGrain": null
                        }
                      ],
                      "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                    },
                    "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/providers/diagnosticSettings"
                  }
                ],
                "variables": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "equals": "true",
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled"
              },
              {
                "equals": "true",
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled"
              },
              {
                "equals": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId"
              }
            ]
          },
          "name": "setByPolicy",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/749f88d5-cbae-40b8-bcfc-e573ddc772fa",
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/92aaf0da-9dab-42b6-94a3-d43ce8d16293"
          ],
          "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings"
        },
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }
}
```

Does someone know how this can be fixed?

Any help would be appreciated.